# Docusign developer account reverts back to trial account

Tags: docusignapi

I initially created a trial account.  Discovered that was incorrect then created a developer account.  Everything seemed good until I timed out and tried signing back in.  The new password used to create the developer account was no longer valid.  DocuSign had reverted my account login back to the original trial account.  This has happened every time I created a Developer account.  I am currently up to my 12th dev account creation.  Verifying every time.  At least all the fields are prepopulated so I don't have to type everything.

How do I prevent DocuSign account management from reverting my Developer account back to a Trial account?  I contacted their support directly but they didn't know and suggested I ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are logging on to demo.docusign.net and that you are going to the following page to set up your dev account. [Create Dev Account](https://secure.docusign.com/signup/developer)

When you first login to your account make sure the url is demo.docusign.net. Demo accounts are on a completely separate server system than the production system.

Support should also be able to look up your account information by e-mail to see where your accounts are located and what the status of them are. If you have an enterprise account, I would make sure to have your enterprise account number when you call in. This will put you with the enterprise support group, which typically handles these issues more frequently.